# Project Euler #2 in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

**Background**

I am stuck on this problem:

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
>
> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

I tried to discover if the issue was my Fibonacci number generator, the code which gets the even numbers, or even the way that I add the numbers to no avail.

**Code**

I decided to store the numbers in lists. Here, I create them.

```
list_of_numbers = [] #Holds all the fibs
even_fibs = [] #Holds only even fibs
```

Then, I created my generator. This is a **potential area of issues**.

```
x,y = 0,1 #sets x to 0, y to 1
while x+y <= 4000000: #Gets numbers till 4 million
    list_of_numbers.append(y)
    x, y = y, x+y #updates the fib sequence
```

Then, I created some code to check if a number is even, and then add it to the `even_fibs` list. This is another **weakpoint in the code.**

```
coord = 0
for number in range(len(list_of_numbers)):
    test_number = list_of_numbers [coord]

    if (test_number % 2) == 0:
        even_fibs.append(test_number)
    coord+=1
```

Lastly, I display the information.

```
print "Normal:  ", list_of_numbers #outputs full sequence
print "\nEven Numbers: ", even_fibs #outputs even numbers
print "\nSum of Even Numbers:  ", sum(even_fibs) #outputs the sum of even numbers
```

**Question**

I know that this is a terrible way to ask a question, *but what is wrong?* Please don't give me the answer - just point out the problematic section.

Comment: `for number in range(len(list_of_numbers)):test_number = list_of_numbers [coord]` can be translated to `for test_number in list_of_numbers`.  Then you can get rid of `coord`.

Comment: +1 for "Please don't give me the answer - just point out the problematic section."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're stopping when the sum of the next two values in the sequence is greater than 4,000,000. You're meant to consider all values in the sequence *up to* 4,000,000.

Comment: Thanks so much - it has been bugging me for a while.

Comment: Another way of saying this is [1, 4000000).